# A simple formula about matrix needed proof

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

I have a very simple question, but I do not know if I am right. Suppose we have a $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix $A$, i.e., $A=A^T$ and also we know that $A$ is invertible. Provided with a $n\times 1$ vector $b$, will we have $Abb^TA^{-1}=bb^T$ ? And if it is right, how can I prove it ?

Comment: Have you tried some examples?   Say for $n=2$?  Try a diagonal matrix $A$, but not the identity.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $A$ is symmetric and invertible, we have 
$$
(bb^TA)^T = A^T bb^T =Abb^T =bb^TA 
$$
if and only if $bb^TA$ is symmetric.

Thus in general, the equality $Abb^TA^{−1}=bb^T$ does not hold.

$\textbf{Counterexample}$: let 
$$
A=\pmatrix{
2 & 3 \\ 
3 & 1 \\ 
} \hspace{4mm}
\mbox{ and } 
\hspace{4mm} 
b = 
\pmatrix{
2 \\
1 \\
}. 
$$
Then 
$$
Abb^TA^{-1} = 
\pmatrix{
1 & 4 \\ 
1 & 4 \\ 
} 
\hspace{4mm} 
\mbox{ while }
\hspace{4mm} 
b b^T = 
\pmatrix{
4 & 2 \\ 
2 & 1 \\ 
}. 
$$

Comment: Thanks...My bad...I am trying to solve an exercise in the book <Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning> (problem 2.37) about the multidimensional Robbins-Monro algorithm. It seems that I may try another way...